# Capture Keyboard events with an ASP.NET MVC application from the server PC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, keystroke

I have an ASP.NET MVC application hosted on a Windows 10 machine via IIS Express and I want to be able to capture keyboard strokes on the server computer (not the client side from the web browser window but the server itself).

I tried MouseKeyHook library which works fine on global events on Winforms projects but not in ASP.NET MVC projects. Is there any other way to do this?

**Update:**
I ended up self hosting the web app from a console app and IIS Express and then configured the barcode reader to work as Serial USB device rather than a HID Keyboard, SerialPort object is used to communicate with it, much faster and more elegant than keyboard strokes.

Comment: Capturing keyboard events on a server side is very strange task. What is original purpose?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 Session isolation.

Comment: @Maradik i have a web app and i need to capture a barcode scanner's input which is connected to the server via USB and acts as HID keyboard, at the moment i have a winforms app which capture the keyboard strokes and sends it locally to the server side via an API, but it would be better if that is a part of the web app solution

Comment: @JOHNWHICK I don't know details. But in general your current solution with API is better, because you can deploy your web server anywhere (and one instance only) and have thin applications only on workstations.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there is no way to fulfill your requirements. iis or windows service application can not capture user interaction. no matter it is a mouse click or keyboard interaction.its not allowed.

Comment: Correct. IIS (not IIS Express) runs in Session 0 where Windows Services run, which has a separate desktop environment and does not have access to the local console session (Session 1). While it is possible to override this on a per-service basis, IIS is not designed for this and will probably crash _hard_. While IIS Express does run in a local user's session, it's a PITA to allow external connections.

Comment: Im not using IIS, im using IIS Express, how can it be done?